# How to add a Recycler View to an activity in Java

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have tried to create `RecyclerView` in an `Activity`, but I don't get the correct way to add a `RecyclerView`.
I searched on the Internet and saw a lot of videos on it, but the method is different on every website, so I was confused.
I want to create a `RecyclerView` that displays flags and Names of all the list of countries in Asia.

Here is my code

**Main Activity**

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.view.*

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        lateinit var recyclerDashboard: RecyclerView

        lateinit var layoutManager:RecyclerView.LayoutManager
        
        val sumList= arrayListOf("Russia","China","India","Kazakhstan","Saudi Arabia","Iran","Mangolia","Indonesia","Pakistan","Turkey","Mayanmar","Afghanistan","Yemen","Thailand","Turkmenistan","Uzbekistan","Iraq","Japan","Vietnam","Malaysia",
        "Oman","Philippines","Iaos","kyrgyzstan","Syria","Combodia","Bangladesh","Nepal","Tujikistan","North Korea","South Korea","Azerbaijan","United Arab Emirates",
        "Georgia", "Sri Lanka","Bhutan","Tiwan","Armenia","Israel","Kuwait","Timor Leste","Qatar","Lebanon","Cyprus","Pelastine","Brunei","Bahrain","Singapore","Maldives")

        lateinit var recyclerAdapter: DashboardRecyclerAdapter

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            recyclerDashboard=findViewById(R.id.recyclerDashboard)
            layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
            recyclerAdapter= DashboardRecyclerAdapter(sumList)
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerDashboard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_dashboard_single_row" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Data Class**

```
    data class User(
        val id:Int=0,
        val country_name:String?=null,
        var country_capital:String?=null,
        var country_flag:String?=null,
        var country_region:String?=null,
        var country_subregion:String?=null,
        var country_population:String?=null,
        var country_borders:String?=null,
        var country_languages:String?=null
    )
```

**Adapter Class**

```
    package com.bindu.asiancountries
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    class DashboardRecyclerAdapter(
        val itemList:ArrayList<String>
    ):RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val v=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_dashboard_single_row,parent,false)
            
            return ViewHolder(v)
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return itemList.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val text=itemList[position]
        
            holder.textViewName.text= text
        }

        class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val image:ImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.russia)
            val textViewName :TextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRussia)
        }
    }
```

**Item xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardElevation="4dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:id="@+id/russia"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/russia"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtRussia"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/russia"
                    android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
                    android:textSize="30sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/russia" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try this..... https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-recycler-view?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change your `RecyclerView` initialization code to:

```
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            recyclerDashboard = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerDashboard).apply {
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
                adapter = DashboardRecyclerAdapter(sumList)
            }
        }
```

The errors in your code were not setting the adapter and the layout manager to the `RecyclerView`.
Infact:

1. With `layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)` you were setting the **parent** view layoutManager
2. After `recyclerAdapter= DashboardRecyclerAdapter(sumList)` you didn't set your adapter to the `RecyclerView`, but you just initialized your global variable